# full size flash inside web browser aligned centre

Tags: asp.net, html, flash

how do can I make the below full size flash inside my web browser aligned centre?

```
<body bgcolor="#000000">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"  codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,19,0" width="50%" height="900">
      <param name="movie" value="css/index.swf" />
      <param name="quality" value="high" />
      <embed src="css/index.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></embed>
    </object>



    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible. AFAIK, the only way to trigger full screen Flash is having the user click a full screen button.

Comment: ahhh sorry i mean full size aligned centre of the page: will edit

Comment: @pekka: I'm working on a full-screen web app in Flash right now.

Comment: @jhocking one that automatically goes into full-screen mode when you point your browser to a page?

Comment: yes, you can put fullscreen properties in the HTML to embed the swf

Comment: oh wait I just thought of something that we need Garrith to clarify. @garrith: Do you mean fill the browser window or fill the screen without the browser visible? I assumed the former while other people are correct for the latter situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set width="100%" in the "embed" tag, not just in the "object" tag. Incidentally, the size you currently have set in the "object" tag is 50%. Oh and you'll probably want to set the page margins to 0.

To then adjust the placement of objects in reaction to the stage resize use stage.stageWidth

Incidentally, the specific embed method you are using is what you get when you publish from Flash directly, and that positions things differently than the embed method when you publish from FlashDevelop. FlashDevelop inserts some JavaScript that centers automatically without the developer having to do anything. I didn't until just now even notice that, it's pretty convenient.

Answer (score 0):

To go full screen in flash you have to change the [`displayState`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Stage.html#displayState) of the [`stage`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Stage.html). The following line would accomplish this:

```
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
```

Comment: sorry was a typo on my part kevin

Comment: I've never heard of that property before, which would imply that is not the only way since that's not how I do it.

Comment: @jhocking: How have you accomplised full screen then?

Comment: oh wait I just thought of something that we need Garrith to clarify. Does he mean fill the browser window or fill the screen without the browser visible? I assumed he meant the former while your answer is correct for the latter situation.

Comment: @jhocking: I'm guessing he means the former, although I'll leave my answer here anyways.